# How to send an array of checkbox values via AJAX to PHP in the right format?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays, ajax

I have a set of checkboxes, that contain bits of SQL Code in their value. If they're checked, they should be send via ajax to my php file and be embedded in my query.

I'm only experienced with simple single variable ajax transfer and i just can't make the examples I find online via google or on stackoverflow to work.

My ajax call:

```
$("#button1").click(function(e) {
    var category_id = {};
    category_id['checkboxvalue'] = $('.checkboxes:checked').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "allgemein.php?id=" + Math.random(),
        dataType: "html",
        data: category_id,
        success: function(response) {
            $("#resulttable").show().html(response);
        }
    });
});
```

My checkbox form:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" name="checkb[]" value="MASTER.SYSTEM LIKE '%systemA'">System A</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" name="checkb[]" value="(MASTER.SYSTEM LIKE '%systemB' OR MASTER.SYSTEM LIKE '%systemC')">System B/C</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" name="checkb[]" value="MASTER.SERVICE LIKE '%serviceX%'">Service X</label>
```

Now in my php I want to use the array like this:

```
$strWhere = '1=1';

if(true === isset($_POST['checkboxvalue']) && 0 < sizeof($_POST['checkboxvalue']))
    {
        $strWhere .= 'AND (';
        foreach($_POST['checkboxvalue'] as $checkboxval)
        {
            $strWhere .= '"%'. $checkboxval .'%" OR ';
        }
        //remove last OR
        $strWhere = substring($strWhere, 0, -3);
        $strWhere .= ')';
    }
```

Then add $strWhere to my SQL Where clause.

Comment: `data: category_id:category_id`

Comment: @Drudge how do you mean? normally, when I'm not sending arrays but just singular, multiple values `data:category_id`, works fine..

Answer (score 0):

`.serialize()` gives you a string of form encoded data.

Passing an object to `data:` will cause jQuery to encode the values in the form as form encoded data.

Since you have *already* encoded that data, you don't want to *reencode* it.

Pass the string directly.

```
data: $('.checkboxes:checked').serialize(),
```

> What can I do, if I have to send a variable via data: because I have other values in it?

If you pass `data` an object then it gets passed through jQuery.param. You can do that manually:

```
data: $('.checkboxes:checked').serialize() + "&" + jQuery.param({
  some: "other",
  data: "values"
}),
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What can I do, if I have to send a variable via `data:` because I have other values in it? (I minimized my ajax call for this question.. )

Comment: Do you mean like 
`data: $('.checkboxes:checked').serialize() + "&" + jQuery.param({
  data: category_id 
}),
success: function(response) {
            $("#resulttable").show().html(response);`
?

Comment: Thank you I will try it out asap

Comment: I have another question. Even if this ajax call works, how would I be able to call the checkboxvariables in my php? Before with `category_id['checkboxvalue']` I was able to call them via `$_POST['checkboxvalue']` but when I pass the string directly - how can I get to them in php? Sorry for the cascade of questions :( I would be really greatful for an answer

Comment: `$_POST['checkb'][]` because that's the name of the input.

Comment: uff sorry, should have figured out that myself :) thank you for your help!